# Recursively find an element

Tags: java, recursion

I have a data structure that looks like a tree:

```
A -> A 
  -> A
  -> A -> A -> A
       -> A
       -> A
       -> A
```

Basically `A` can be composed of another `A` or multiple `A(s)`.

I want to find a particular `A` with an ID.

```
public A findParticularA(int id)
{
    if(this.getID == id)
    {
        return this;
    }

    else
       findAHelper(this, id);
}

public A findAHelper(A root, int id)
{
    for(A a : root.getChildren())
    {
        if(a.getID == id)
           return a;

        else
            findAHelper(a, id);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This only works when the `A` that I am looking for is right after the first root `A`.

```
  A -> A
    -> **A**   will be found
```

But if I want an `A` that is deeper in the tree then it will not work. This is because I am not returning correctly. Please help.

Comment: It does not. I tried before.

Comment: Are you sure `root.getChildren()` is behaving as expected?

Comment: `findAHelper(this, id);` should be something like `a = findAHelper(this, id); if(a!=null){return a;}`

Comment: *"This only works when"* No it doesn't, because that code will not compile, so it never works. No when's, if's, or but's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to return the reult of findAHelper in `findParticularA`.

In `findAHelper` the loop makes you drop deep down three branches of the tree; hopefully an A will come back up from those branches, but it won't come back from all of them, only one. The rest (or all of them) will return null.

So you need to catch the return value of findAHelper, see if it's null or not, to decide whether to return it - if it's an A (not null), return it, otherwise don't and let the loop continue down the next tree branch.

I can't write it properly in Java off the top of my head, but the change I suggest is:

```
public A findParticularA(int id)
{
    if (this.getID == id) 
    {
        return this;
    }  
    else 
    {
        return findAHelper(this, id);  # here
    }
}

public A findAHelper(A root, int id)
{
    for(A a : root.getChildren())
    {
        if(a.getID == id) 
        {
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = findAHelper(a, id);    # here
            if (tmp is not null) {       #
                return tmp               #
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one method. You don't need the `findParticularA`

```
public A findA (A root, int id)
{
    if (root.getID == id)
        return root;

    A[] children = root.getChildren(); 

    A res = null;
    for (int i = 0; res == null && i < children.length; i++)
    {         
        res = findA(children[i], id);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Just call it with:

```
A a = findA(this, id);
```